# Check if value change in loop while with a class

Tags: php

I want to print:

```
if($this->year_info !== $year_now){

                $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->f_info. " FRST <br>";
             if ($this->month_info < $this->l_info+1){
                $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->l_info. " LAST <br>";
                $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->s_info. " SENM <br>";
            }
        }
```

if the year change:

```
Year
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

I want to print once for year 1 and once for year 2.

I would like to check if the year will change, but I am stuck in this part.

First I am executing a while and inside I am sending to a class.

Do you have any idea how I can check?

```
     class printInfo {

    public $year_loop;   
    public $month_loop;
    public $f_loop;
    public $l_loop;
    public $s_loop;

    function __construct($year_loop, $month_loop, $f_loop, $l_loop, $s_loop) {
        $this->year_info = $year_loop;        
        $this->month_info = $month_loop;
        $this->f_info = $f_loop;
        $this->l_info = $l_loop;
        $this->s_info = $s_loop;
    }

    function getData($operation, $detail) {

        if ($operation !== null) {

            $year_now = $this->year_info;

            $dataToPrint = $this->year_info . "  " . $this->month_info . "  " . $operation . "<br>" . $detail . "<br>";


            if($this->year_info !== $year_now){

                    $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->f_info. " FRST <br>";
                 if ($this->month_info < $this->l_info+1){
                    $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->l_info. " LAST <br>";
                    $dataToPrint .= $this->year_info . "  " .$this->s_info. " SENM <br>";
                }
            }
            return $dataToPrint;


        }
    }
}

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $pon = $rows["cop"];    
    $printInfo = new printInfo($rows["year"], $rows["month"], $rows["cf"], $rows["cl"], $rows["cs"]);

    if ($pon !== $pob) {
        echo $printInfo->getData($pon, $rows["cdp"]);
    }
    echo $printInfo->getData($rows["coi"], $rows["cdi"]);
    echo $printInfo->getData($rows["coh"], $rows["cdh"]);
    echo $printInfo->getData($rows["cof"], $rows["cdf"]);

    $pob = $rows["cop"];   
    $year_before = $rows["year"];
}
```

Comment: Maybe a new class or extended class?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean not to print for any row when the year is the same as the previous row, then:

```
$year_before = null;

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($year_before == $rows["year"]) {
        continue;
    }

    // …

    $year_before = $rows["year"];
}
```

If you want to prevent printing if the year has appeared in any of the previous rows, then:

```
$printed_years = [];

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(in_array($rows["year"], $printed_years) {
        continue;
    }

    // …

    $printed_years[] = $rows["year"];
}
```